# I'm trying to do a teleport script in Unity 3d I'm not an expert

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Here is the script but when I load it shakes the ground and then slowly vibrates behind the character the teleport itself kinda works

```
public float range = 1000f;
public float tprange = 100f;
private Transform Destination;
public int mana = 100;
public int currentmana;
public Camera Camera;
public GameObject Player;
public ManaBar ManaBar;
bool isteleporting;

void Start()
{
    currentmana = mana;
    ManaBar.SetMaxMana(mana);
    isteleporting = false;
}

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.E))
    {
        teleport(20);

    }
}

void teleport(int consume)
{
    currentmana -= consume;
    ManaBar.SetMana(currentmana);
    isteleporting = true;
    RaycastHit hit;
    if (Physics.Raycast(Camera.transform.position, Camera.transform.forward, out hit))
    {
        if (hit.rigidbody )
        {
            GameObject impactGO;

            Player.transform.position = hit.point;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably need to add your characters collider's bounds(character's size) into the equation. Your character directly goes into the hit.point meaning probably goes into a wall and while unity's physic system solves it, you are experiencing that slow vibration.

Answer (score 4):

Çağatay IŞIK is right. The code works but it sends you right in to the place your raycast hit. Which means half of you is inside that hitbox. Than Unity collision physics slowly move your player out of the wall. You need to do something like this:

```
float playerSize = 10;
Player.transform.position = hit.point - ((hit.point - Player.transform.position).normalized * playerSize);
```

Comment: I reviewed the game a few times and I found out that the position of the player just gets continuously updated in a disorganized manner and that causes what I described as strong vibration